# How do I start a Single Player/Multi Player game with a custom map in Starcraft II?

Tags: starcraft-2

This may sound a little bit silly, but I can’t seem to find how to do this.

Single Player -> Vs. A.I. seems the way for single player, but then I can’t find a way to select my map. I only see a list of blizzard maps.

If, on the other hand, I start a multi player, I get all the ladder nonsense. I can create a custom game (or play cooperatively) but then again, the map selector list doesn’t allow me to “move” to a different folder; I can’t find the maps in the starcraft folder either…

Any ideas?

I’m used to play on a couple of custom maps that I’m porting to SCII, we used to LAN play (lame that that’s not possible anymore), however, I don’t care to use BNET, if I can use my map. I must be doing something wrong…

In essence, how do I create a Map and use it in a custom game? Do I have to publish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom game selection will allow you to draw from maps that you have uploaded to battlenet via the Galaxy Editor.  As I understand it this is exactly what you want to do and it sounds like you do understand how to publish a map.

I believe there is an option to publish the map privately for custom game use, though I haven't check since Beta.

Comment: Thanks. THat did it. Tho the publish thing I’m not sure I like too much, but after you figure out how to do it, it’s ok. You can make it private too. The annoying part is that you cannot stay connected to BNET with the editor and the game at the same time… (it logs you off from either). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to publish it for single-player.  Simply drag the map-file onto Starcraft-2's icon to start up that map in single player.  Alternatively, you could open the map in the map editor and hit *"test map"*.