# How to load a custom sc2Map map?

Tags: starcraft-2

I created a custom map and I want to try it now.
Where to put the map?
Now is in c:\Program Files\Stracraft II\Maps.
However, when I start the game and look into "Single game -> Standard -> My maps" it is not listed there.
I want to test the map against AI. So I need to go through the menu that allows me to add AIs to the map before playing.

---

Note: I have managed to load the map in SC2 by using the sc2switcher.exe. However, this does not allow me to play the map against the AI. As soon as the game starts, I win the game, because I play against no opponents.

Comment: There is a "test map" button in the editor...

Comment: Voting to leave open as [map editor questions are on-topic](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/544/185203)

Comment: There is a somehow similar question here but it does not really answer my question about how to actually play against AI. But I thought to link it anyway, because it might be useful for others :)  https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3798/how-do-i-start-a-single-player-multi-player-game-with-a-custom-map-in-starcraft